# Can't insert records from Excel to SharePoint

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sharepoint, ado

Currently I am suffering Excel ADO issue.

Here is the thing taht
I was trying to insert some records 
from "Excel table" to "SharePoint list" Using ADO connection.
But failed (Can't recognize Excel table in SQL Statement)

```
Dim SQL        As String
Dim CN         As New ADODB.Connection
Dim OLEDB      As String
Dim LIST       As String
Dim SITE       As String

LIST = "{EE028282-3D7E-4D37-93EE-50FB69C4432C}"
SITE = "https://asml.sharepoint.com/teams/FFKR_DUV_YS_Installation_and_Relocation/Product"
OLEDB = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
         "DATABASE=" & SITE & ";" & _
         "LIST=" & LIST & ";"

Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
CN.Open OLEDB

    SQL = SQL & "INSERT INTO Schedule_DB (NAME,TYPE_W) "
    SQL = SQL & "SELECT * "
    SQL = SQL & "FROM [" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[S_RAW$] "

    CN.Execute CommandText:=SQL
CN.Close
```

If I run it I got error ->
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5euLZ.png)

I have already check the miss-spell, and the amount of item is too much, so I would prefer to process it as a one SQL statement.
"Excel to Excel" works well But still have no ideas for "Excel to SharePoint List".
Please share your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to read data from your Excel sheet you need to have a `ADODB.Connection` with *Read permission*, then to write data to your SharePoint List you need to have another `ADODB.Connection` with *Write permission*.

> Note: You can't transport your whole data in that way, You can generate a big command with whole data then use it or generate command for each record of your Excel data.

About your exception it is simply says it can't find your sheet name in SharePoint Lists.

---

A sample to guide you can be something like this:

```
Dim cnnXl As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsXl As New ADODB.Recordset    
Dim cnnShP As New ADODB.Connection

conStrXl = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\yourExcel.xlsx';" & _
         "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"

commandXl = "SELECT [Field1], [Field2] FROM [Worksheet$$A1:D7] WHERE [Thing1] > 1"

conStrShP = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
            "DATABASE=yourSite;LIST={yourListCLSID};"
```

Then open `cnnXl` and run `commandXl` and read data to `rsXl`.
Then open `cnnShP` and loop over `rsXl` records and create your `commandShP` and execute it.

Comment: Thank you shA.t,  Could you explain more detail on [ loop over rsXl records and create your commandShP and execute it ] I am getting excited there can be the answer!

Comment: Use a sample for a [loop over a recordset like this] that you can create a SQL command like `insert into Schedule_DB (NAME,TYPE_W) values ('name','type');` then execute this command using connection to SharePoint(`cnnShP`) ;).